# Custom error mode in web.config

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config

In my web.config file, I have set the custom error mode is set to "Off". But still its re directing to the default page. Anybody know why its happening like this. First I have set some custom pages in the project but I removed that later.

I'm using Visual studio 10

Comment: Can you share here the whole <customErrors> section here?

Answer (score 0):

Also, if the code is deployed. Check the default listing in IIS for default pages.
If you are having issues with web.config. You can read Microsoft ASP.Net Web Configuration guidelines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400235%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) .